# Align table each other horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this table but I am not able to put them side by side horizontally, I tried many things but I am clearly missing something, what would you recommend? I am struggling with those columns.

Update:
I have 7 tables, they do have 3 columns but the number of row is different from each other.
I am using a theme bootstrap v4. Whenever I do a `class="table"` it goes all wrong.

[image]

```
<div class="table">

<table class="table-striped" style="display: inline-block; float: left; ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:200px;"> Module </th>
      <th style="width:120px;"> Info </th>
      <th> Value </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


<tr>
<td> ACU  </td>                 
<td> Fls </td>             
<td> 0</td> </tr>
<tr>
<td>  Mode</td>                    
<td> Trk</td>              
<td> 3</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>  Use</td>                 
<td> PS</td>          
<td> 43</td> 
</tr>

  </tbody>
</table>




<table class="table-striped" style="display: inline-block; margin-left:150px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:200px;">  Module </th>
      <th style="width:120px;"> Info </th>>
      <th> Value </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tag2>
        <tr>
        <td> PBit</td>          
         <td> Lock</td>    
         <td> 1</td> 
         </tr>
        <tr><td> Bit</td>         
          <td> NA</td>       
          <td> 0</td> 
          </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> it</td>          
         <td> Lock</td>    
         <td> 1</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> Bit</td>         
          <td> NA</td>      
          <td> 0</td> 
          </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> Bit</td>         
        <td> Lock</td>    
         <td> 1</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> Bit</td>         
        <td> NA</td>       
        <td> 0</td> 
        </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? the table cells are displayed horizontally... also `display:float` means nothing

Comment: @ATomCalledStu, I have 2 tables that I need to get them side by side and not aligned vertically. I couldn't put more code in the question.

Comment: There is only one table in your example. Do you have another table you haven't shown? Or do you want to align two parts of the one table shown?

Comment: @Bman70 I couldn't put 2 tables because I need more text than code for the system letting me post

Answer (score 1):

Just change your table `position` to `inline-block`. This will allow your table elements to be positioned on the same line horizontally as one another. You should do this in a css file or in the `head` of the document rather than inline if possible. Also, for reference, `display:float` is not valid css. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpovjs1y/) for you.

```css
table{
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block; 
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Module </th>
      <th> Info </th>
      <th> Value </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Mode</td>                    
      <td> Track</td>             
      <td> 3</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> A</td>               
      <td> PS</td>          
      <td> 43</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Module </th>
      <th> Info </th>
      <th> Value </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Mode</td>                    
      <td> Track</td>             
      <td> 3</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> A</td>               
      <td> PS</td>          
      <td> 43</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried the same thing but it's not working at all unfortunately, it is still the same display

Comment: @Mohamed Well you can see in the fiddle that it’s clearly working. If you want help here you’ll need to post more code or recreate the problem in a fiddle. Not sure why you can’t post your code here. There is no limit to how much you can post.

Comment: try with flexbox

Answer (score 1):

I added extra `merge_table` div that wrap your two table inside it so, after i can use `flexbox` to get table side by side.

I used `d-flex` class, stands for `display: flex` and for distinguish between two table i added `ml-3` stand for `margin-left`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="merge_table d-flex">
    <table class="border">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Module </th>
                <th> Info </th>
                <th> Value </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> Mode</td>                    
                <td> Track</td>             
                <td> 3</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> A</td>               
                <td> PS</td>          
                <td> 43</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="border ml-3">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Module </th>
                <th> Info </th>
                <th> Value </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> Mode</td>                    
                <td> Track</td>             
                <td> 3</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> A</td>               
                <td> PS</td>          
                <td> 43</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't do a dumping, you are added with difference functionality and i added answer with `flexbox`. so its total different way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <style>
        .tbl{
            border : 1px solid black;
            float: left;
            margin:  0 5px;
        }
        .row{
            margin: 5px;
        }
        .clear{
            clear: both;
        }

    </style>

    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <table class="tbl2 tbl">
                <tr>
                    <td>2-11</td>
                    <td>2-12</td>
                    <td>2-13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-21</td>
                    <td>2-22</td>
                    <td>2-23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-31</td>
                    <td>2-32</td>
                    <td>2-33</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table class="tbl2 tbl">
                <tr>
                    <td>2-11</td>
                    <td>2-12</td>
                    <td>2-13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-21</td>
                    <td>2-22</td>
                    <td>2-23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-31</td>
                    <td>2-32</td>
                    <td>2-33</td>
                </tr>
            </table>


            <table class="tbl3 tbl">
                <tr>
                    <td>2-11</td>
                    <td>2-12</td>
                    <td>2-13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-21</td>
                    <td>2-22</td>
                    <td>2-23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-31</td>
                    <td>2-32</td>
                    <td>2-33</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <table class="tbl4 tbl">
                <tr>
                    <td>2-11</td>
                    <td>2-12</td>
                    <td>2-13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-21</td>
                    <td>2-22</td>
                    <td>2-23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-31</td>
                    <td>2-32</td>
                    <td>2-33</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table class="tbl5 tbl">
                <tr>
                    <td>2-11</td>
                    <td>2-12</td>
                    <td>2-13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-21</td>
                    <td>2-22</td>
                    <td>2-23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-31</td>
                    <td>2-32</td>
                    <td>2-33</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table class="tbl6 tbl">
                <tr>
                    <td>2-11</td>
                    <td>2-12</td>
                    <td>2-13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-21</td>
                    <td>2-22</td>
                    <td>2-23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-31</td>
                    <td>2-32</td>
                    <td>2-33</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <table class="tbl7 tbl">
                <tr>
                    <td>2-11</td>
                    <td>2-12</td>
                    <td>2-13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-21</td>
                    <td>2-22</td>
                    <td>2-23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-31</td>
                    <td>2-32</td>
                    <td>2-33</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

output is :

[image]

Comment: Not only is this a code dump with no reference or explanation, it’s also a copy of the answer above, just with less work put in and bad practice with inline style. Not cool.

Comment: @ATomCalledStu I have updated the post with more detail

Comment: @ATomCalledStu i have solve this using float: left property.

Comment: @Amarat I tried, it works but they are aligned horizontally based from the bottom,. How can I define the position such as : `row 1 table1 table 2 table3` then `row 2 table4 table5 table5` ?

Comment: @Mohamed if you don't need to change in html then use .tbl {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 32%;}

Comment: @Amarat No, you just added more tables and added an “output”. This is a bad answer, and bad practice in this community. It works, but it’s poorly constructed and it’s a copy of my answer. I realize you are new here, so please review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Amarat float left is doing nothing here. You are using inline block display.